# JQM load the html page in the pagecontainer

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a basic requirement, can somebody kindly help me please?

I have two HTML pages:

Page #1 --> JQM page

Page #2 --> is a basic HTML page with some `<div>`'s.

Now the requirement is that I need to show the Page #2 content in the specified container of Page #1.

I have tried using `$.mobile.loadPage()` and unfortunately it does not work. Can somebody please help me with this? I am pasting the code below.

Page #1 Code:

JS :

```
  <script>
     $('#MyPage').live("click", function() {  
      var dataurl = $(this).attr("data-url");  
        if (dataurl != null)  

            $.mobile.loadPage("/marq.html",{
                pageContainer:$("#myCont"),
                data:dataurl


            }); 
    });
    </script>
```

HTML :

```
<div data-role="page" id="MyPage">
    <div data-role="header" class="header" role="banner">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="myCont">
```

Thanks
RAvI

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need is to load data from one document into another with an AJAX call:

```
<script>
$('#MyPage').live("click", function() {  
    var dataurl = $(this).attr("data-url");  
    if (dataurl != null)  

    $("#myCont").load('marq.html #id_of_element_to_grab');
});
</script>
```

This example uses `.load()` to grab the data from your second document. The selector that comes after the document location is the element you want to grab from the second document (known as "Loading Page Fragments").

Here is the documentation for `.load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load/

`$.mobile.loadPage()` requires that the page being loaded uses the jQuery Mobile structure of: `<div data-role="page">[Page Contents]</div>`